# Print arraylist of queues separated by commas

Tags: java, arraylist, queue

I want to print the values of an arraylist that's filled with queues, but i want to do it separated by a comma.

This is what i'm doing to print the list:

```
for(int i=1;i<listaOfQueues.size();i++){
      System.out.println(listaOfQueues.get(i).toString()+"\n");
    }
```

This is my current output:

> 242424242424242525252525252526262626262626
>
> 272727272727272828282828282829292929292929
>
> 303030303030303131313131313132323232323232
>
> 333333333333333434343434343435353535353535
>
> 363636363636363737373737373738383838383838
>
> 393939393939394040404040404041414141414141

My desired output:

> 24,24,24,24,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,26,26,26,26,26
>
> 27,27,27,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,29,29,29
>
> 30,30,30,30,30,30,30,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,32,32,32,32,32,32,32
>
> 33,33,33,33,33,33,33,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,35
>
> 36,36,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,38,38,38
>
> 39,39,39,39,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,41,41,41,41,41,41,41

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: The problem is not the code above but the toString method of the object.  You need to modify the toString method to include a comma between each value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.join()` method.

```
System.out.println(String.join(",", listaOfQueues.get(i))+"\n");
```

In fact you can use `String.join()` on any class that implements the `Iterable` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use collector transformations and mappings

```
listOfQueues.stream().map(a ->
            a.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(
                    Collectors.joining(","))
    ).collect(Collectors.reducing((a, b) -> a + "\n" + b)).get().toString()
```